# How simple bound jQuery ajax and Django?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I try use pure jQuery for ajax with Django.
For test i try send data, then return some data.
ajax.js:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/realty/ajax/test/',
        data: 'test',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^ajax/test/$', ajax.test),
)
```

ajax.py:

```
def test(request):
    return HttpResponse(request)
```

But, alert is empty, like 'request' empty. But [there is look like work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476357/django-ajax-get-request).

Comment: do you get any error in web console? Seems like `/realty` is missing in the urls.py

Comment: Atterratio, please check if my answer solves your problem. If so, mark it as correct please. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should return serialized data in the view:

```
import json
def test(request):   
    result = {'result': True}
    returned_json = json.dumps(result)
    return HttpResponse(returned_json, mimetype="application/json")
```

And in your javascript:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/realty/ajax/test/',
        data: 'test',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.result);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

This is going to show you an alert with a true value.